# Prooving that p devide $C_n^k$ (Related to Fermat's Little Theroem)

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

Let $p$ be a prime number, and $k$ be an integer with the following property:  $1\leq k \leq p-1$.
Why can't we just say that
$$C^k_n=\frac{p!}{k!\cdot(p-k)!}=p\frac{(p-1)!}{k!\cdot(p-k)!}=pK\implies p/C^k_n$$
for $K\in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: If you mean to say that $p \mid \binom{p}{k}$ (or in your notation $C_p^k$), you're correct! (assuming $k \neq 0,p$ of course.)

Comment: Then why all the proofs use Gauss' property to prove it?